# Postgres pg_read_all_stats default role cannot read from my schema

Tags: postgresql, configuration, monitoring

I have a postgres user created with the `pg_read_all_stats` default role permissions which states the user should be able to read as if superuser. This works fine for any of the `pg_stat_*` tables.

However I need some data from the `pg_stats` table. These queries do not show rows for my applications in the `public` schema.

The documentation does not indicate how this table should behave when interacting with my applications public schema. Am I completely out of luck for querying this table with `pg_read_all_stats` permissions?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the definition of `pg_stats`:

```
SELECT ...
FROM pg_statistic s
  JOIN pg_class c ON c.oid = s.starelid
  JOIN pg_attribute a ON c.oid = a.attrelid AND a.attnum = s.staattnum
  LEFT JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
WHERE NOT a.attisdropped AND has_column_privilege(c.oid, a.attnum, 'select'::text)
  AND (c.relrowsecurity = false OR NOT row_security_active(c.oid));
```

you can see that you need to have `SELECT` rights on the column in question to see the statistics.

The underlying table `pg_statistic` can only be examined by the bootstrap superuser.

One way to work around this is to create a function owned by a superuser with `SECURITY DEFINER` that selects from `pg_stats` and returns the results.

Make sure to

- `REVOKE EXECUTE` on this function `FROM PUBLIC`.
- `ALTER FUNCTION ... SET search_path = pg_catalog, pg_temp;`

Comment: Unfortunately it still does not work, as the default role `pg_read_all_stats` explicitly only returns on tables that it already has access to. Since it can't access `public` by design, it can't do it.

Comment: `GRANT SELECT ON pg_statistic TO normaluser;` and then the user can select from `pg_statistic`.

Comment: `normaluser` will still be unable to read from the `pg_statistic` of schemas it does not have access to. A secondary step of `GRANT` on the schemaname is required which we don't want in our case.

Comment: I have added another idea.